# Avoid enormous network payloads

Tags: plugins, ads

Running a WP site, so asking here.

Google speed test shows
"Avoid enormous network payloads - Total size was 8,265 KB"

- (static.doubleclick.net) - 514.2 KB
- (static.doubleclick.net) - 514.2 KB

And several more of doublick that seems pretty huge to me.

So Adwords is causing this? Or something in WP configuration?

Comment: i guess you play several banners on your site and each is adding the doubleclick script on it's own? It could be Adwords causing it. Should not be a strange WP config. But to debug this some more information is needed.

Comment: Yep I use Adwords, several of them on website.